# Add html to a site in a site (proxy)

Tags: html, proxy, replit

I imported a web proxy from github known as rhodium on to replit, and, after some editing was satisfied with the results, but i cant seem to add HTML to a site that is proxied. Example: You use rhodium to navigate your way to [www.discord.com](http://www.discord.com), but you want HTML added to the page, "yourdomain.example/service/https://discord.com/". I looked at the files and online, but I wasn't able to find a way to edit the index.html of that specific page, but frankly I am extremely new to html. (and to a lot of things web-development).
https://github.com/LudicrousDevelopment/Rhodium
Any help available?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Based on what i know, you can't. Because of the security parameters. You can't attach or redirect a website which isn't on the same directory/server.

You can, however redirect to that site, inside or outside, freely.